# Syntax error or access violation using OUTPUT keyword

Tags: php, pdo

I'm attempting to make use of the OUTPUT line so I don't have to use multiple queries to get information that I've inserted into a table. This is for a basic image uploader project that will rename the images based on their id in the database.

Here's the query I'm using (Using it with PDO)

```
INSERT INTO `images` (`id`, `type`, `category`, `title`) VALUES (null, :type, :cat, 'Newly uploaded image') OUTPUT INSERTED.id;
```

-

```
Processing upload
Error uploading file: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OUTPUT INSERTED.id' at line 1
```

I've read over a few different tutorials now and I'm really confused as to what the problem is.

Comment: `OUTPUT` is not MySQL. SQL maybe. Not MySQL.

Comment: Try using [`lastInsertId`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

OUTPUT is not working in MYSQL.
Use

```
 SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

after your insert query